# Access a specific task inside a Fargate service

Tags: aws-fargate

I'm new to aws so forgive me if the question is trivial.

I have a Cluster running a single fargate service with two tasks that is hosting my internal api service.  I can access the api via the main level and everything works.

`https://<serviceid>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/lookupx` will return the lookupx result from one of two tasks as determined by the load balancer.

I would like to get the result from each task. I know the ein for each task and I know the private IPs.

What do I need to do in in order to access a specific task in a call?

Why do I care?  The service reads 40+ files from s3 at startup into memory and provides an endpoint to lookup a value and return corresponding data. I'd like to add an endpoint to reload a file on demand, but I need to make sure both tasks get updated. Not my design and I do not have time and budget to rebuild. Just looking for a better solution than restarting the tasks, reloading all 40+ files, just to update one. Wasn't bad with weekly updates, kinda sucks with daily updates.

Comment: Why do you need it? The answer from both tasks should be identical. If you only have a private IP then you can make the request from another machine inside the same VPC. You can also change the service configuration so that tasks have public IPs.

Comment: The service reads 40+ files from s3 at startup into memory and provides an endpoint to lookup a value and return corresponding  data.  I'd like to add an endpoint to reload a file on demand, but I need to make sure both tasks get updated.  Not my design and I do not have time and budget to rebuild.  Just looking for a better solution than restarting the tasks, reloading all 40+ files, just to update one.  Wasn't bad with weekly updates, kinda sucks with daily updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice private IP can change after task is restarted.

You can run extra scheduled/on demand task with the same or different task definition to find the service via AWS API, get its current tasks and their IPs and then call your API for all of them.

the script can be bash or any other supported language
https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/

with bash
you can list all service tasks:

```
aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <clusterName> --service <serviceName>
```

and their ip:

```
aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster <clusterName> --tasks <taskARN1 taskARN2> --query 'tasks[].attachments[].details[?name==`privateIPv4Address`].value[]'
```